# Changing the "OT Process" Plugin's Default Slug of /process/

Tags: plugins, permalinks

I'm working on a site, aspacehomedesign.com. We are trying to get the content from **/process-a/** to display on this slug **/process/**. We created the **/process-a/** page, while the **/process/** is the *default slug for the "OT Process" plugin*. In other words, I'm trying to change the slug of **/process/** to something different. I'm having difficulty changing the slug because I don't believe it's in the plugin file editor and not in the permalinks section in settings. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What is the function of the "OT Process" plugin? I was able to find that it's by OceanThemes, but couldn't find any other info on it.

Comment: Changing a third-party plugin is off-topic here - this site is all about custom code. That said, first don't change anything in the plugin file editor - every time you update the plugin, your changes get lost. Research "how to change a custom post type slug" - if you can code just a little, you can create your own plugin which un-registers and re-registers the post type with the slug you are trying to put everything under.